# How to link from an existing webform iis hosted application to a react asp mvc app?

Tags: reactjs, iis, model-view-controller, webforms

I have an existing webform app hosted as the default website on iis and the default react+redux mvc asp core app that comes with visual studio in a subfolder of this default webform app.

how do i use an href from the webform app to launch the react mvc app.

i get the error below when the href just links to the subfolder name:

[image]

Comment: Why did you down vote me?

Comment: ASP.NET Core web app should be hosted in its own site and application pool. Use reverse proxy to modify its URLs if you need.

Answer (score 0):

lex thanks for the input.

i was able to get it to work finally.  i used one website, modified the root folder of this default website down one level from the original root for the webforms application.  i then created anther application for the react+redux mvc in the new root folder along side my original web forms app.  now i can use the same url just modifying the end to navigate between the two.

www.example.com/webformsapp/index.apx

www.example.com/reactaspmvcapp/